# Hazelcast: set max size, eviction policy on ReplicatedMap

Tags: configuration, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

This is my first time working with Hazelcast. I am trying to configure a Hazelcast cluster for my application. For our use case, I need to define multiple replicatedmap's in my application.

I have read through the documentation (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#replicated-map) and the actual implementation of ReplicatedMap (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/config/ReplicatedMapConfig.java) provided by Hazelcast.

My question is, just like the Hazelcast Map, which provides us means to configure max size, eviction policy, etc. for the Distributed Map, how do we specify the same properties for a replicated map?

I did not see any way to specify the max size and eviction policy in the replicatedmap. We cannot let the Replicated Map grow as much as it can.

I appreciate any pointers to get me going on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify eviction of entries of replicatedMap programmatically  by using the method

```
V put(K key,
      V value,
      long ttl,
      TimeUnit timeUnit)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Riaz. Having a TTL set on each record being inserted will take care of entries being evicted in a timely manner. But how about the max size!! Think of a situation where the TTL on all records is 60mins and the application see's a surge of traffic in an hour. Technically we could end up inserting so much data in the cache that the heap could run out of space before the 60mins expire causing the application to come down. There should be a max size setting on the replicatedMap. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. Try to check the map size everytime an entry is added, within an Event Listener.

Comment: Don't you think it's an overkill to check the size every time we add an entry. Also the question remains, how will you enforce an eviction policy if your check of cacheFull() returns true.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit max-size policy for replicated maps. Any such policy will have to be implemented by the application ensuring the same entry is removed from all copies